# How i can solve this error with Googleapis auth and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a script that automatically creates files in a specific folder in my google drive account, but I got this error and i cant auth I'm using google service account instead of 0Auth

error:25066067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could

this is my code

```
   async function createFile({ folderId, title, data }) {
  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: "credentials.json",
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  });

  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });

  // TODO(developer): set folder Id
  // folderId = '1lWo8HghUBd-3mN4s98ArNFMdqmhqCXH7';
  // This is a simple sample script for retrieving the file list.
  drive.files.list(
    {
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) return console.log("The API returned an error: " + err);
      const files = res.data.files;
      console.log(files);
    }
  );
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong, I try to search but I didn't find anything

Comment: I found lots of info to your error message, pointing to debian buster or Ubuntu 22.04 and OpenSSL. So, on wich OS are you running?https://askubuntu.com/questions/1409458/openssl-config-cuases-error-in-node-js-crypto-how-should-the-config-be-updated

Comment: @HEllRZA I'm using ubuntu 22.04